# Difference between $1 vs %1 in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What is the difference between `%1` and `$1` in .htaccess?

For example,

```
    #  to remove www  
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w+)\.mydomain\.com [NC]

    RewriteRule .* http://mydomain.com/%1 [R=301,L]    
    #    versus
    #    RewriteRule .* http://mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I have been using [Dave Child's .htaccess cheat sheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/download/mod_rewrite-cheat-sheet-v2/pdf/) and [Jackol's .htaccess cheat sheet](http://www.thejackol.com/htaccess-cheatsheet/) as well as the [Apache mod_rewrite docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html) but additional help would be great.

Comment: The `mod_rewrite` docs say `%N` backreferences are for RewriteCond patterns while `$N` backreferences are meant for RewriteRule patterns.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

`%1` Refers to a pattern matched in a `RewriteCond` condition, while `$1` refers to a pattern matched inside a `RewriteRule`.

More generically, use `%n` to refer to the numbered matches from `RewriteCond` condition regex patterns, and use `$n` to refer to numbered matches from `RewriteRule` regex patterns.