# Crawlable AJAX with _escaped_fragment_ in htaccess

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, url-rewriting, web-crawler

Hello fellow developers!

We are almost finished with developing first phase of our ajax web app.
In our app we are using hash fragments like:

```
http://ourdomain.com/#!list=last_ads&order=date
```

I understand google will fetch this url and make a request to the server in this form:

```
http://ourdomain.com/?_escaped_fragment_=list=last_ads?order=date&direction=desc
```

everything is perfect, except...

I would like to route this kind of request to another script

like so:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^$ /webroot/crawler.php$1 [L]
```

The problem is, that when I try to print_r($_REQUEST) in crawler.php I get only:

```
Array
(
    [_escaped_fragment_] => list=last_ads?order=date
    [direction] => desc
)
```

what I'd like to get is

```
Array
(
    [list] => last_ads
    [order] => date
    [directions] => des
)
```

I know I could use php to further break the first argument, but I don't want to ;)

please advise

====================================================
EDIT... some corrections in text and logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your forgot QSA directive (everyone missed the point =D )

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^$ /webroot/crawler.php%1 [QSA,L]
```

By the way your `$1` is well err... useless because it refers to nothing. So this should be:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^$ /webroot/crawler.php [QSA,L]
```

Tell me if this works.

Comment: I think it should be '%1' instead of '$1' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654834/difference-between-1-vs-1-in-htaccess

Comment: Then you should drop that comment about the $1 as well.

Comment: In his question there's a line of code : `RewriteRule ^$ /webroot/crawler.php$1 [L]` The `$1` is useless: either it's `%1` like you said, or it's `RewriteRule (.*) /webroot/crawler.php?someparam=$1 [L]` but it's not correct like it was written.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^$ /webroot/crawler.php?%1 [L]
```

Comment: Its better if in crawler.php add print_r($_GET); output will be an array  [ Array ( [order] => date .... )  ] not string like in other examples

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is obvious for you, but in the documentation talk about escaped characters:
[Set up your server to handle requests for URLs that contain](http://code.google.com/intl/ca/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html)

> The crawler escapes certain characters in the fragment during the transformation. To retrieve the original fragment, make sure to unescape all %XX characters in the fragment. More specifically, %26 should become &, %20 should become a space, %23 should become #, and %25 should become %, and so on.

Comment: I had some problem witch "&26" so i write simple fix:

if ( strstr($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],'%26') ) :
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] = urldecode($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $_GET );
endif;

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that provides a routable URL and query parameters correctly set for processing in the server side script.

Example:
 If you want `http://yoursite.com/#!/product/20` to become `http://yoursite.com/crawler/product/20`

First in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^$ /crawler/index.php?_frag=%1  [L]
```

We need to get rid of the `_escaped_fragment_` in the URL and replace it with something different, example: `_frag` so that the (Apache) web server does not get in to circular rewrites.

Second in `crawler/index.php`

```
<?php

if(array_key_exists('_frag', $_REQUEST)) {
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=$_REQUEST['_frag'];
    unset($_REQUEST['_frag']);
    parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $frag); 
    parse_str(preg_replace('/^.*\?/', '', $frag['_frag']), $_REQUEST);
    $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] = http_build_query($_REQUEST);
}

// Continue with your usual script of routing
// $_REQUEST now contains the original query parameters
```

Answer (score 0):

In htacess work in virtual host not working, so i add in "directory"

```
<Directory "X:/DIR">
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^$ /crawler/index.php?_frag=%1  [L]
</Directory>
```