# ?_escaped_fragment_ in apache config

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, single-page-application

I am trying to make my single page application [crawlable by google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/174992?hl=en) and for this reason I have to implement redirect for urls that starts with `?_escaped_fragment_`.

I found this [highly relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063287/crawlable-ajax-with-escaped-fragment-in-htaccess) and a nice answer there (there are couple of duplicates there as well). I tried both approaches (before both of them I have `RewriteEngine On`):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^$ /webroot/crawler.php%1 [QSA,L]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^$ /webroot/crawler.php [QSA,L]
```

But in both cases I my urls `http://localhost/?_escaped_fragment_` are not redirected. My apache has no problems during restarts.

I assume that the problem can be because I am modifying my apache.conf file (`/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`) and not the `.htaccess`. I also enabled `a2enmod rewrite`.

I also added this into my apache.conf:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
</Directory>
```

Does anyone has an idea what might be the problem?

Comment: A few ideas (probably most of them are done by you, but maybe not.):
You should turn on mod rewrite as well.
You should verify if it works. (with something trivial, or enable its logging.)
Maybe it is enabled only for an other vhost, or inside an other context.

Comment: @LajosVeres thanks but I wrote that I enabled it by running `a2enmod rewrite`

Comment: AFAIK enable loads only the module. I don't think it adds 'RewriteEngine On'.

Comment: @LajosVeres I also added `RewriteEngine On`. And I also wrote about it.