# AJAX - Google Crawling and 'Fetch as Google'

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, google-crawlers, hashbang

I have a question regarding Google crawling and AJAX.

This is how my url looks like:

```
example.com/#!contact
```

I know that Google and other search engines use `?_escaped_fragment_=` to replace the hash tag in order to get a certain page.

When I try:

```
example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=contact
```

it takes me to the index page and not contact.

I used this small piece of PHP where I usually load the ajax data, and now 'Fetch as Google' gets the content.

```
<div id="content">
    <?php

        if(isset($_GET['_escaped_fragment_'])){

            $newID = $_GET['_escaped_fragment_'];

            include_once $newID.'.php';
        }

    ?>
</div>
```

Is this ok to use? IF crawling (using _escaped_fragment_) include this page with php, otherwise its a client and get him the page via ajax?

Thanks

Comment: That's pretty much how google intended it :) so props for you!

Comment: Thank you very much, good news! :) If someone finds .htaccess config for this too, it would be more than appreciated.

Comment: What about [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8233390/777850)? Looks like what you need :)

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you very much! Don't get how to up-vote comments... :D