# .htaccess Rewrite rules: what is the differences between %1 and $1 variables (percentage vs dollar sign)?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

All my rewrite rules up to this moment used $1, $2... variables to form a clean URL.

Now I need to redirect basing on a part of domain name (`http://subdir.example.com` => `http://example.com/subdir`) and many examples I found using %1 variable instead of $1 format. I should note that `subdir` is an arbitrary string.

This is unclear for me. I'm trying to find the meaning of $1 and %1 variables for hour or two and still can not find anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdir\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdir/
RewriteRule (.*) /subdir/$1
```

Make sure you clear your cache before testing it.

A suggested edit from OP:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/????/
RewriteRule (.*) /????/$1
```

Comment: Could you make your code more general just in case `subdir` can be any arbitrary string? I think that it is the right place to use `%1`, which would be closer to the core of the question. Thanks!

Comment: I've included it as an edit, but not removed the original. Always good to keep both versions for people to test. However, I'm not 100% sure why you wanted `subdir` removed. This is their for people to replace, it has the same use as `example`.

Comment: Oh! You've included my question marks :))) I hoped that you will replace them with right code. Could you?

Comment: I came across this question:  [Difference between $1 vs %1 in .htaccess.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654834/difference-between-1-vs-1-in-htaccess) - I think this is what you're after.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I'm looking for. I think that these questions should be linked together in a style "*This question already answered here...*". Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Flagged as duplicate :)