# Access matching groups .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess/regex_

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^img.test.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/([1-9]|1[0-2])\/(.*-?)\d{13}-([1-9]|1[0-2]{1})_ico.jpg
RewriteRule   ^(.*) $1 [R=301]
```

My matching URL is `http://img.test.com/12/this-is-a-test-690-cable-1234567891234-12_ico.jpg` which should result in 3 captured groups

- Group 1. 1-3 `12`
- Group 2. 4-29    `this-is-a-test-690-cable-`
- Group 3. 43-45   `12`

How can I access those groups? `$1` returns the full match and `$2` returns `http://img.test.com/`.

Comment: I just updated my question.

Comment: Remove `^` at the beginning. https://regex101.com/r/RCJNkU/1

Comment: Still returns the same for $1 and $2.

Comment: I don't know about the rest but your regex is good. Change `.` to `\.`. You should match a dot, not any character `.`.

Comment: To get the http value You need to match against %{HTTP_HOST} variable  in a `RewriteCond`  like
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)$` and then you can use `%1` to get that match.

Comment: The solution was to use % instead of $.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6654857/1405318